# Execute Applescript in Sites Folder

Tags: macos, applescript

I search every where on the web to the information below :
How to execute a applescript in the "Sites" folder. Let me explain :
I have made a litthe script (PHP) which execute an applescript which open a file
applescript :

```
tell application "Finder"
open file "Macintosh HD:Utilisateurs:my-user:FOO.pdf"
end tell
```

my php script :

```
exec("osascript ShutDown.scpt");
```

When i execute it from localhost, it's working. But when i'm accessing it with Sites folder
http://my-user.home/myPhpScript.php it's not working. You can find the error in apache below :

```
my-user.home osascript[1323] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @  
CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer,     
_CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
```

Do you know any solution to make it work ?

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 4):

The `www` user cannot use `osascript`. You'll have to edit the apache config file to run as your user. This works but isn't very secure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll only use it in my local network. The thing I don't understand is why localhost can execute it, whereas Sites folder cannot... I'll try to check the two httpd.conf file. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If running the script directly from the web page won't work because of permissions, try working around it. Have PHP create a file in a folder that is generally empty within the Sites folder. Then use either folder events or an idle handler script to check that folder for the file and if one exists execute the functionality you need.